# Rails 4.0 nested object forms not rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models in my app: "WorkPost" and "Contacts".

**WorkPost**

```
 class WorkPost < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :contacts
 end
```

**Contacts**

```
 class Contacts < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :work_post
 end
```

In my controller's `new` method I do:

```
def new
  @work_post = WorkPost.new
  @work_post.contacts
end
```

And in view I create form:

```
<%= form_for(@work_post) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label 'Vacation' %><br>
<%= f.text_field :post_title, :placeholder => 'Vacation here' %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label 'Vacation description' %><br>
 <%= f.text_area :post_body, :placeholder => 'Vacation description here' %>
</div>
  <% f.fields_for :contacts do |cf| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= cf.label 'Email' %><br>
    <%= cf.text_field :emails, :placeholder => 'Email here' %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit "Post vacation", :class => 'btn_act' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

But it seems like line `<% f.fields_for :contacts do |cf| %>` doesn't work.
Everything is rendered fine but email field.What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line

```
<% f.fields_for :contacts do |cf| %>
```

which should be

```
<%= f.fields_for :contact do |cf| %>
```

Also, the `class name` for the `model` and the `association name` for `has_one/belongs_to` should be ***singular***.

```
#work_post.rb
class WorkPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :contact #should be singular
end

#contact.rb
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base #should be singular
  belongs_to :work_post
end
```

Also, notice the change `:contacts` to `:contact`, as it is a `has_one` association.

***Update:***

Also, try the below changes

Include `accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact` in `work_post.rb` model

```
#work_post.rb
class WorkPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :contact
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact
end
```

Change the `new` method to below

```
def new
  @work_post = WorkPost.new
  @work_post.build_contact
end
```

Comment: I did everything as you said but still no render :(

Comment: No, I just can't see any html code in page source. I added line `<% puts("work post is #{@work_post} and its contact is  #{@work_post.contact}") %>` to see values in terminal and while in my 'new' method 'contact' was declared as '@work_post.contact' it was nil and now I changed line to @work_post.build_contact and now it is an object in terminal log, but view still not render my field

Comment: I've added `accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact` line too. Still no luck

Comment: @vendettacore Try restarting the server once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91642/discussion-between-vendettacore-and-pavan).